# Check variables from different lines with awk

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sh

I want to combine values from multiple lines with different lengths using awk into one line if they match. In the following sample match values for first field, 
aggregating values from second field into a list.

Input, sample csv:

```
222;a;DB;a
222;b;DB;a
555;f;DB;a
4444;a;DB;a
4444;d;DB;a
4444;z;DB;a
```

Output:

```
222;a|b
555;f
4444;a|d|z
```

How can I write an awk expression (maybe some other shell expression) to check if the first field value match with the next/previous line, and then print a list of second fields values aggregated and separated by a pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS=";"}
  { if ($1==prev) {sec=sec "|" $2; }
    else { if (prev) { print prev ";" sec; };
           prev=$1; sec=$2; }}
  END { if (prev) { print prev ";" sec; }}'
```

This, as you requested, checks the consecutive lines.

Comment: Thanks! This script worked as expected, doing the job. I was trying to look for the next line (getline) using the previous one is easier :D

Answer (score 1):

does this oneliner work?

```
 awk -F';' '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"|"$2:$2;} END{for(x in a) print x";"a[x]}' file
```

tested here:

```
kent$  cat a
222;a;DB;a
222;b;DB;a
555;f;DB;a
4444;a;DB;a
4444;d;DB;a
4444;z;DB;a

kent$  awk -F';' '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1]"|"$2:$2;} END{for(x in a) print x";"a[x]}'  a
555;f
4444;a|d|z
222;a|b
```

if you want to keep it sorted, add a `|sort` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have set the field separator ( -F ) to ; :

```
{
   if ( $1 != last ) { print s; s = ""; }
   last = $1;
   s = s "|" $2;
} END {
   print s;
}
```

The  first line and the first character are slightly wrong, but that's an exercise for the reader :-). Two simple if's suffice to fix that.

(Edit: Missed out last line.)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I overlooked the "second field" specification and concatenated the whole lines. Edited the fix. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: this is almost right, but you want to init `s` with `s = $1;`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly convoluted, but does the job:

```
awk -F';' \
'{
  if (a[$1]) {
    a[$1]=a[$1] "|" $2
  } else {
    a[$1]=$2
  }
 }
 END {
   for (k in a) {
     print k ";" a[k]
   }
 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

Command:

```
awk -F';' '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1]"|"$2}else{a[$1]=$2}}END{for (i in a){print i";" a[i] }}' fil
```

Input:

```
222;a;DB;a
222;b;DB;a
555;f;DB;a
4444;a;DB;a
4444;d;DB;a
4444;z;DB;a
```

Output:

```
222;a|b
555;f
4444;a|d|z
```